# What's a good tutorial on how to deal with different "states"?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, state-machine, states

Just a tutorial to cover the basics of state machines and design patterns.

Comment: +1 just *and* a star just because I'm partial to FSMs

Answer (score 0):

From this [**Google list**](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=finite+state+machine+tutorial&cp=22&qe=ZmluaXRlIHN0YXRlIG1hY2hpbmUgdA&qesig=DcXDWd1rSkYzWBrZ0ix6LQ&pkc=AFgZ2tkaiJtRqXVhjUfiyrZCwkFO4dsq_U5QTXgX9nOBYt1mupFDqDetGoT-K1XuzOoPOKByoUE7OKI2fdGcOFGBYYAvwRfuHw&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=finite+state+machine+t&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=38378e84586d88e6), there's a nice one on [**Widipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Answer (score 0):

The [Portlands Pattern Repository's Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WelcomeVisitors) has a few hints and pointers: [StatePattern](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?StatePattern).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.state-machine.com.